# Magento getChildHTML from a different class

Tags: magento

On the login page's phtml file there is a line that adds the html for a remember me checkbox using: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>`

I want this same checkbox to also appear in a different part of the website, but when I add this same line to that section's phtml, nothing shows up. I logged out the classes of the `$this` object in the two files, for the login page its `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login`, and for the other section its `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`.

I'm guessing the difference in classes causes the remember me to not be found in the other sections call to add it. Is there any way to add this remember me html to this page even though their `$this` classes are not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code in place of your code

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('persistent/form_remember')->setTemplate('persistent/remember_me.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Or add following code to add block in your page's handle to use your same code with $this

```
<block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
```